# How to define a computed column

Tags: 2010, content-type, feature

I'm creating a custom content type in I need two fields *Submitter* and *Date Uploaded* which would have the same values are *CreatedBy* and *Created* How do I define it? I have the following definition

Field definitions

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Field ID="{3C700F8D-A421-404B-B6C6-DC3D66FDFBB7}" Type="User" Name="Submitter" ShowInNewForm="FALSE" DisplayName="Submitter" Description="Person who submitted the statement.">
    <FieldRefs>
      <FieldRef Name="CreatedBy" />
    </FieldRefs>
    <DisplayPattern>
      <MapToContentType>
        <Column Name="CreatedBy" />
      </MapToContentType>
    </DisplayPattern>
  </Field>
  <Field ID ="{BE5810A3-2947-4DE1-AC2D-2CA87E18F8D0}" Type ="Computed" Name="DateUploaded" ShowInNewForm="FALSE" ShowInEditForm="FALSE" DisplayName="Date Uploaded" Description="Date statement was uploaded.">
    <FieldRefs>
      <FieldRef Name="Created" />
    </FieldRefs>
        <DisplayPattern>
      <MapToContentType>
        <Column Name="Created" />
      </MapToContentType>
    </DisplayPattern>
  </Field>
 </Elements>
```

Content Type definition

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <!-- Parent ContentType: Document (0x0101) -->
  <ContentType ID="0x010100116625b359fe4441ba033e7175911437"
               Name="Statement"
               Group="Custom Content Types"
               Description="Statement Content Type"
               Inherits="TRUE"
               Version="0">
    <FieldRefs>
      <FieldRef ID="{3C700F8D-A421-404B-B6C6-DC3D66FDFBB7}" Name="Submitter" />
      <FieldRef ID="{BE5810A3-2947-4DE1-AC2D-2CA87E18F8D0}" Name="DateUploaded" />
      <FieldRef ID="{7A9C198E-D843-4A68-ADA7-6666B0B296D0}" Name="Issues" />
      <FieldRef ID="{B4DF0D6A-D5F4-458A-A55F-558397008D63}" Name="StatementMonth" />
    </FieldRefs>
    </ContentType>
</Elements>
```

But this isn't working. Should I be using calculated columns instead?

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that the actual field for Created By is "Author" so you should use that instead.